# Spring Boot Runs on Tomcat 8.5.x but not 8.0.37 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/UpgradeProtocol

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8, noclassdeffounderror

relatively new to Spring so I am guessing I am not doing something correctly. I have been converting an older java soap service to spring.  I am able to run it locally on tomcat 8.5 and up, but when I run it on tomcat 8.0.37 (which is what the server I will deploy it to is on) I get the error below. I came across this error in another project, but realized in the other project I was unnecessarily creating a servlet, so once I ripped out the servlet code I was good to go. In this instance I need to create a servlet. The error is looking for "org/apache/coyote/UpgradeProtocol" which is not in Tomcat 8.0.37. Not sure what in my code is trying to use it. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Tomcat dependencies in pom...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

error...

> 2019-01-17 16:05:12,539 SEVERE Class= org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  Method= addChildInternal  Message= ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/exampleServices]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'containerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/removed/exampleServices/exampleServicesConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory]: Factory method 'containerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/coyote/UpgradeProtocol
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)

config class below, I assume the issue is with how I am creating my TomcatServletWebServerFactory or my ServletRegistrationBean

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.exampleservices", "com.example.examplesoapservices"})
@Configuration
@EnableAWSF
public class exampleservicesConfiguration {


static {
    // Statically initialize SystemImpl so it doesn't slow down first
    // request
    try {
        SystemImpl.getInstance();
    } catch (exampleException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(), "/exampleservicesSOAP/*", "/exampleservicesSOAPV3/*");
    //ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(), "/exampleservicesPort/*", "/exampleservicesPortV3/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setEnabled(true);
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(0);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}


@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public SpringBinding springBinding(exampleservicesSOAPImpl exampleservicesSOAPImpl, AWSFHandlers awsfHandlers) throws Exception {
    SpringBinding springBinding = new SpringBinding();
    springBinding.setUrl("/exampleservicesSOAP");
    SpringService springService = new SpringService();
    springService.setBean(exampleservicesSOAPImpl);
    springService.setHandlers(awsfHandlers.getAwsfHandlers());
    springBinding.setService(springService.getObject());
    return springBinding;
}

@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public SpringBinding springBindingV3(exampleservicesSOAPV3Impl exampleservicesSOAPV3Impl, AWSFHandlers awsfHandlers) throws Exception {
    SpringBinding springBinding = new SpringBinding();
    springBinding.setUrl("/exampleservicesSOAPV3");
    SpringService springService = new SpringService();
    springService.setBean(exampleservicesSOAPV3Impl);
    springService.setHandlers(awsfHandlers.getAwsfHandlers());
    springBinding.setService(springService.getObject());
    return springBinding;
}

@Bean
public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor(){
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory  containerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory () {
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath(exJAXBContext.JAXB_CONTEXT_PATH);
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}

@Bean
private static JAXBContext initContext() {
    try {
        return JAXBContext.newInstance(BasicServiceComponents.eesvcof.getClass().getPackage().getName() + ":" + BasicServiceComponents.eesvcofV3.getClass().getPackage().getName());
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}


private static final JAXBContext context = initContext();

@Bean
public Marshaller marshaller() {
    Marshaller marshaller = null;
    try {
        marshaller = this.context.createMarshaller();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //any setters
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public Unmarshaller unmarshaller() {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
    try {
        unmarshaller = this.context.createUnmarshaller();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //any setters
    return unmarshaller;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well , most probably it is because Spring Boot 2.0 series requires Tomcat 8.5 which is mentioned in the [release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/spring-boot-2.0-release-notes#third-party-library-upgrades). That `UpgradeProtocol` is something related to HTTP2 which does not exist in Tomcat 8.0 , so your best bet is try to disable HTTP2 in the application.properties :

```
server.http2.enabled=false
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but my tomcat instance is too old (7.0.85).  Strangely, on a slightly newer version 7.0.108 it doesn't give the error/exception but when I try to hit the endpoint I get a 404 exception, so it likely is not going to work.  Next step is try newer version of tomcat 9.0.x

Answer (score 0):

So the code that was breaking is

```
 @Bean
 public TomcatServletWebServerFactory  containerFactory() {
     return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory () {
         protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
             super.customizeConnector(connector);
         }
     };
 }
```

When I was testing before I was commenting this out and when I would run locally I would get a different error.  Someone I work with suggested removing this bean (I guess it is not needed with spring 2) and also removing my pom code that specifies the tomcat version. This worked. So locally spring is managing my Tomcat version.  I believe spring sets Tomcat to 8.5.35 for the spring 2.0.7 release.  When I deploy my code  it now runs fine on Tomcat 8.0.35.  So you do not need that bean, and when running locally just let spring set your own Tomcat version. I am not sure why that bean works on Tomcat 8.5.35 but I don't need it anyways.